# Getting all the users who have author privilege

Tags: database, wpdb, users

Can anyone tell me how to get all the users who have author privileges by querying the DB in WordPress and order them by number of posts written by them.

I use the following query to get all the users from DB:

```
$authors = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name"
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you want to retrieve custom data from the database, you will hardly ever need to make use of the [`WPDB`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class (or its global object, respectively). Though it is obviously possible to do things that way as well.

Just for the sake of completeness, *if* you had a reason to not use a more abstract function, you'd have to employ [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) in the select syntax as user roles live in the *usermeta* table.

But it'd be much simpler to make use of the [`get_users`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function:

```
$args = array(
    'role'         => 'author',
    'orderby'      => 'display_name'
);
$authors = get_users( $args );
```

**[EDIT]** As for the question in the comments (ordering by the number of posts):

Use `'post_count'` as an argument for the `'orderby'` parameter (and read the linked codex page, which gives you all the possible arguments).

Comment: What about ordering it by the number of posts?

Comment: @MidhuN See revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array();
$args['fields'] = array( 'ID', 'display_name' );
$args['role'] = 'author';
$authors= get_users( $args );
```

Reference : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

Comment: What about ordering it by the number of posts?